# why can't get the resource by using $r('app.string.tab_title1'+1)

Tags: resources, ets

my pc's os is windows10,and I found a question while I'm programing,I can't get resource by using $r('app.string.tab.title'+1) while using $r('app.string.tab.title1') is ok.Why?(I'm editing a file whose name ended with .ets)

I think the connection with strings is ok,the reason is about the $r()? where to find its source code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.